# How to see samba shares when running a Nios II shell as administrator under Windows 7

Tags: cygwin, samba, intel-fpga, nios

I'm running into some problems with some Nios II code I'm trying to run using Quartus Web Edition 13.1 running under Windows 7.

One of the problems I'm seeing is that if I launch the Nios II shell as an administrator and then run the "df" command, I don't see my samba shares mounted.  When I'm run the shell as my normal user (who also happens to be an administrator) I see the shares and can access them just fine.

The Nios II shell uses a cygwin bash shell.  Is there some cygwin setup that I need to do to get the shares to show up when I run the shell as an administrator?

Comment: As a follow-up to my original question.  I've started running the Quartus tools under CentOS in a VM.  This allows me to access all of my local and network drives without any problems.  Also, I don't have any of the USB driver issues I had under Windows when I communicate with my dev boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped drives are per user session in Windows (which is how e.g. multiple users on a Terminal Server can all have separate "H:" drives mapped to different shares). When you run a process as an administrator on Windows, it is actually isolated and does not have access to the mapped drives in your session.

Comment: I actually enabled the Windows 7 administrator login account, logged in as the administrator and mapped the same shares but to no avail.  I guess those mappings are only good for interactive sessions?

Comment: Correct. Mappings in an interactive administrator login session won't be accessible to a process in another session elevated to administrator.